# Blank pages when creating and downloading a PDF file (iText & JSF)

Tags: jsf, pdf, jsf-2, itext

I'm having a problem when I try to create a PDF file using iText and want to download it immediately afterwards. First I create a PDF file using the iText library, the file is written to a TEMP folder on the server, this all works fine. But afterwards I call a download screen for downloading the PDF file from the TEMP folder to the client, and here something goes wrong. The download screen shows a Firefox (browser) icon instead of the Acrobat icon. When I donwload the file I only get to see blank PDF pages, but the number of pages is correct. E.g. I have a PDF file of 4 pages, I get 4 blank pages as a result, there is no content. The PDF file in the TEMP folder however is correct, it has got 4 pages with the correct content.

This is my java code, it is executed when the user clicks a h:commandLink

```
     public <E> String createPDF(E type, boolean print) throws Exception {

            Document document = new Document();
// create a File name for the document
            getPdfNaam(type);
            try {
//create a PDF writer
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(TEMP + naam + ".pdf"));
//open the PDF document
                document.open();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    //build the PDF file using iText
            buildPDFContent(document, type);
    //close the PDF document
            close(document);

            String downloadFile = TEMP + naam + ".pdf";
    //call Servlet for download screen in the browser
                ServletContext context = (ServletContext) ContextProvider.getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getContext();
                HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ContextProvider.getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getResponse();
                response.setContentType("application/force-download");
                downloadFile = TEMP + naam + ".pdf";
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                try {
                    File file = new File(downloadFile);
                    long length = file.length();
                    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                    response.setContentLength((int) length);
                    while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(buf)) != -1)) {
                        out.write(buf, 0, (int) length);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
                response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + naam + ".pdf" + "\"");

            return null;

        }
```

I found the code for calling a download screen on this website http://www.winstonprakash.com/articles/jsf/file_download_link.htm
I searched on Google and Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find any related questions. I'm using JSF 2.0 Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content type should be set to `application/pdf` and the content disposition header should be set before any byte is been written to the response, otherwise it's too late to set it. Plus, you can also just write the PDF to the outputstream of the response immediately.

All with all, the method can be simplified as follows:

```
public <E> String createPDF(E type, boolean print) throws Exception {
    getPdfNaam(type); // ??? It should *return* name, not change/set the local value.

    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + naam + ".pdf" + "\"");

    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, ec.getResponseOutputStream());
    document.open();
    buildPDFContent(document, type);
    close(document);
}
```

Also ensure that you're calling [`FacesContext#responseComplete()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#responseComplete%28%29) to signal JSF that you've already taken the response handling in your hands so that it knows that it doesn't need to navigate to some view.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

Comment: The compiler indicates it can't 'find' the method. setResponseHeader(String, String) Thank you already for the tip with the outputstream, much less code. :)

Comment: Then you're *actually* not using JSF 2.0 as indicated in the question. It was introduced in JSF 2.0. See also http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#setResponseHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: Hmm you're right, although the properties of my project in netbeans indicate I'm using the JSF 2.0 library. I'm going to check this out and keep you posted.

Comment: Get rid of any JSF 1.x JAR files and ensure that your `faces-config.xml` root declaration is conform JSF 2.0.

Comment: My project is a Maven project. This is what I have in my pom.xml for JSF:
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>mojarra-jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-b04</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>mojarra-jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-b04</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
Is there something missing/wrong?

Comment: *Disclaimer: I don't do Maven, so I may be utterly wrong.* I believe that `provided` means that it's supposed to be already provided by your container, for example Glassfish. Is this true? Anyway, this is candidate for an entirely different question. Press `Ask Question` if you stucks. Does the above concrete answer work if you just cast the `HttpServletResponse` the JSF 1.x way?

Comment: It should be provided by my GlassFish server, yes. The casting gives me the same result. I just found an exception in my Server Log saying "WARNING: Invalid HTML; bare lessthan sign found at line 4. Surroundings: '</Length 124/Filter/FlateDecod'.
SEVERE: Malformed end tag 'Length' at line 4; skipping parsing. Surroundings: '124/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream'."

Comment: Oh? To be sure, did you call `FacesContext#responseComplete()` in your bean's action method to prevent that JSF navigates to a view after completing the download? Otherwise your PDF response will be corrupted with HTML headers and content.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry that I didn't think about this before, this is namely a very common mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

you can you the outputstream to response immediately. The below is my code:

```
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("application/x-msdownload;charset=utf-8");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;"+"filename="+System.currentTimeMillis()+".pdf");

        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10,10);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
        document.open();
            //The below is document add data
            //....
            //close flow
            if(document!=null){
                document.close();
            }           
            if(out!=null){              
                out.flush();
                out.close();    
            }
```